# how to make a dynamic output using jsf and ajax

Tags: ajax, jsf

I have a dropdown list of bank account numbers, each number has an available balance. what I want to do is when I pick a number from the list it shows an output box saying "Available balance is x". my only concern for now is the front end so I just want to print a random number each time.

I tried using outputbox in JSF but the problem is the box is always there, I just want it if I picked a number.

Comment: Please visit the [help], take the [tour] to see what and [ask]. Do some research - [search SO for answers](https://www.google.com/search?q=javascript+jsf+ajax+dynamic+output+site%3Astackoverflow.com).  If you get stuck, post a [mcve] of your attempt, noting input and expected output using the [\[<>\]](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/358992/ive-been-told-to-create-a-runnable-example-with-stack-snippets-how-do-i-do) snippet editor.